# Getting element content in shadow roots with Pyppeteer

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

I have a JS-path of object that I am interested in. This path contains a lot of shadow-roots.

I am trying to get element content with python google-headless API.
Due to shadow-roots I cant use page.querySelector.

So, probably I have to execute JS-path in the console and get the output.

Is it possible with pyppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

So, It was solved!
The answer is to use page.evaluate command to get console output by JS-path!